# maven dependency should pick jar from local repository

Tags: maven

I have a requirement for my MAVEN build to pick a single jar from my local repository. This jar (in context) is also available in my central repository.

can someone suggest what has to be done in pom.xml? appreciate quick help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope you have a valid reason to do this since this is not a normal scenario.

You could use a different `groupId` and/or `artifactId` to distinguish your jar from the `central` one.  Alternately you could install the `local jar` with a `classifier` to distinguish it from the `central` jar.

Answer (score 2):

Rename the version you depend on be different from the one in the central repository. Put that version in your local repository.